# YouTube API check if user is a subscriber for channel or video

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I have a list of users stored in my db from Google OAuth (only email, username, id). So on frontend part I want to check each of them if they are subscriber for some `channelId` or `videoId`. Note, not for current authenticated user, for all users which I have in my db. In API docs (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list) they only work with mine, I need some sort of `forUserName` I guess. Can someone help to resolve this issue?

Comment: Base on this [SE post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/25480/can-i-view-a-channels-subscribers-on-youtube), there is no way to view who the subscribers and what channel each subscribers subscribed with. Also, I can't see any method in the [YouTube API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/) that will get users profile information.

Comment: that`s sad, should find another way for my application

Comment: @SamPasku isn't this what you are looking for https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list

Comment: my bad, need to clarify, so i have userId(after how he was authenticated), and have channelId, according to this data i need to check that user is he was subscribed to that channel, simple get all subscribers is not good for, because i have limit quates